# Does QBO v3 QueryService limit responses to 100 rows? Can I set a higher limit?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am using QueryService to retrieve a list of customers. This seems to limit the number of returned rows to 100 rows, maximum.

Here is my code:

```
QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer> customerQueryService = new QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer>(serviceContext); 
List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer> customers = customerQueryService.Select(c => c).ToList();
```

How do I set a higher limit for the maximum number of returned rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00300_query_operations

Maximum Number of Entities in a Response

The maximum number of entities that can be returned in a response is 1000.  If the result size is not specified, the default number is 100. If a query returns many entities, fetch the entities in chunks, as described in Pagination.  To determine the number of entities that a particular query returns, probe by using the COUNT keyword in the query.   See Count for details.

Comment: Hi William,

Thank you for your response. I understand. What you're saying is that I can't just call customerQueryService.Select() ... I need to call customerQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery(), specifying MAXRESULTS in the query. So the second line becomes...
List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer> customers = customerQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("SELECT * FROM Customer MaxResults 1000").Select(c => c).ToList();

This works for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dead link, this looks like it might be the updated version: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/learn/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/data-queries